# Why the time cost is more and more larger when reading .mat file and processing it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get 6500 mat flies about **ECG**.
And I want to read it from these files and do some processes about it, but I find the time cost is more and more than what I thought and tqdm estimated before.
So it puzzles me if there is anything wrong with my code.
Here is the mat file example:

```
# the number of each array are given same for convience, in fact they are totally not same    
mat1 = scipy.io.loadmat('Train/TRAIN0001.mat')
mat1
{'I': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'II': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'III': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'V1': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'V2': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'V3': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'V4': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'V5': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'V6': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: nt, Created on: Mon May 6 16:56:48 2019',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'aVF': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'aVL': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'aVR': array([[-0.02928, -0.02928, -0.02928, ... , 0.46848, 0.53192, 0.5856]]),
 'age': array([[63]], dtype=int32),
 'sex': array(['FEMALE'], dtype='<U6'),
}
```

Here is the code:

```
def read_mat(mat_path, index):
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat(mat_path)
    mat_df = pd.DataFrame({
                            'I_' + str(index): mat['I'][0],
                            'II_' + str(index): mat['II'][0],
                            'III_' + str(index): mat['III'][0],
                            'V1_' + str(index): mat['V1'][0],
                            'V2_' + str(index): mat['V2'][0],
                            'V3_' + str(index): mat['V3'][0],
                            'V4_' + str(index): mat['V4'][0],
                            'V5_' + str(index): mat['V5'][0],
                            'V6_' + str(index): mat['V6'][0],
                            'aVF_' + str(index): mat['aVF'][0],
                            'aVL_' + str(index): mat['aVL'][0],
                            'aVR_' + str(index): mat['aVR'][0]
    })

    age = pd.DataFrame({'age': mat['age'][0]})
    sex = pd.DataFrame({'sex': mat['sex']})
    sex['sex'] = sex['sex'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'male' (0 if x == 'female' else 2))

    return mat_df, age, sex

def read_data():

    # target.csv save the label of every people
    tar = pd.read_csv('target.csv')

    # ECG has collected 5000 samples of each people, so I want to treat every sample as a feature
    train = pd.DataFrame(columns=[i for i in range(0, 5000)])
    for i in tqdm(range(1, 6501)):
        tmp_filename = 'TRAIN' + str(i).zfill(4)
        train_tmp, age, sex = read_mat('Train/' + tmp_filename, i)
        train_tmp = train_tmp.transpose()
        train_tmp['age'] = age['age'][0]
        train_tmp['sex'] = sex['sex'][0]
        train_tmp['target'] = tar['label'][i-1]

        # add 5000 samples of each mat file into train DataFrame
        train = train.append(train_tmp)
        del train_tmp, age, sex

    target = pd.Series()
    target = train['target']

    return train, target, tar
```

Here is the time cost:

> 0%         | 11/6500 [00:00<01:01, 105.36it/s] 
>   0%         | 19/6500
>   [00:00<01:08, 94.25it/s] 
>   ...
>    ...
>    10%        | 636/6500 [02:14<39:37,
>   2.47it/s]
>    10%        | 640/6500 [02:15<39:52, 2.45it/s]
>    ...
>    ...
>    20%        | 1322/6500 [09:25<1:12:56, 1.18it/s]
>    20%        | 1328/6500
>   [09:30<1:13:27, 1.17it/s]
>    ...
>    ...
>    30%        | 1918/6500
>   [20:02<1:13:53, 1.23s/it]
>    ...
>    ...
>    40%        | 2586/6500
>   [35:52<1:44:42, 1.61s/it]
>    ...
>    ...
>    50%        | 3237/6500
>   [2:08:11<10:58:41, 12.09s/it]

When I have read 50% mat files, it estimates that it will cost more than 10 hours.
AND I am wondering that is there anything wrong with my code so it will cost too much time.
Could anyone give me some hints on my code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: the proper way to check would have been to run your code through a profiler, which I did not do (as it would require faking input data with somewhat plausible lengths etc.).

Looking at the body of the for loop, the only line that can plausibly increase in execution time is

```
train = train.append(train_tmp)
```

[The doc says specifically to avoid this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) (probably because of a [Schlemiel the painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm) situation):

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.